# Upgrading ProFTPd from 1.3.6c to 1.3.7e fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, proftpd

I am currently testing the 1.3.7e version of Proftpd against 1.3.6c like proposed here [on the projects page.](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Upgrade.html)
Unfortunately I can't get rid of those errors while loading the config. I get

```
./proftpd -t -d10 -c /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
Checking syntax of configuration file
2022-09-15 11:41:40,078 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: using TCP receive buffer size of 87380 bytes
2022-09-15 11:41:40,078 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: using TCP send buffer size of 65536 bytes
2022-09-15 11:41:40,078 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: ROOT PRIVS at mod_core.c:377
2022-09-15 11:41:40,078 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_core.c:379
2022-09-15 11:41:40,078 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: ROOT PRIVS at mod_core.c:386
2022-09-15 11:41:40,078 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: ROOT PRIVS at parser.c:1186
2022-09-15 11:41:40,078 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: fatal: unknown configuration directive 'ModulePath' on line 7 of '/etc/proftpd/modules.conf'
2022-09-15 11:41:40,079 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at parser.c:1189
2022-09-15 11:41:40,079 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_core.c:389
2022-09-15 11:41:40,079 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: warning: unable to include '/etc/proftpd/modules.conf': Operation not permitted
2022-09-15 11:41:40,079 v2202005121494117849 proftpd[24761]: fatal: unknown configuration directive 'ModuleControlsACLs' on line 8 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
```

I checked on those mentioned directives/options which should all be current/essential. Also there is nothing wrong with the permissions of the /etc/proftpd/modules.conf file.

What confuses me is that it does seem to load the modules.conf although it complains beforehand. The `ModuleControlsACLs insmod,rmmod allow user root`is actually in the modules.conf file (not in proftpd.conf), like the `ModulePath /usr/lib/proftpd`. If I comment out these it will just give an error with the next and so on, so it does seem it is not accepting any from that config file.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The `ModulePath` directive is implemented by the `mod_dso` module; if you do `proftpd -l` to list the modules in your old _vs_ new ProFTPD installations, do they have the same modules listed?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the hint. I think I'll have to invest more time into compiling, adding the modules. I'm also thinking about how to put the new version on top of the one I installed from Ubuntu official repos, and how to avoid confusion with the install locations and configs..

Comment: well.. unfortunately this is not going smooth. mod_cap complains about missing declarations. When taken out, next issue is it requires Controls support but mod_ctrls is already included .. my configure cmd looks like this ```./configure --enable-dso --enable-nls \
--with-modules=mod_ident:mod_auth_pam:mod_ctrls \
--with-shared=mod_tls```

Comment: You also need the `--enable-ctrls` configure option, along with `--with-modules=mod_ctrls`, for full [Controls](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Controls.html) support.

Comment: thanks but still no luck. Using --with-modules=mod_ctrls it complains about double compiling it. Omitting it I end up with an issue with the lpam lib. I will now try to go the route [mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316502/how-to-find-proftpd-compile-options-ubuntu-14-04) But I am wondering if there might be any specific reason why Ubuntu is way behind in proftpd versions..